# Using flow, how do I require that an array contains at least one element?

Tags: flowtype

Seems that [the docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/arrays/) say that you can force it to a fixed length. Is it possible to require that an array contains at least one element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this with the `Array` type. "Array with length >= 1" is not a type on its own, it's either an array, or it isn't.

> the docs say that you can force it to a fixed length

This is because at this point the type isn't an array, the type is "a tuple of N values" where a given number of items and their types equates to its own standalone type. Tuples are also considered read-only in that you cannot change their size.

For instance, what would Flow do if you call `.pop()` on the array? It would have to somehow be disallowed because if the length is part of the type itself, changing the length of the array would actually count as changing the type of the object.

If you expect to change the number of items in the array, what you could do is define your own type that validates the size of the array, and then only exposes methods to add items and throws if the size becomes less than 1. At the end of the day these are runtime checks that it would be up to you to maintain.

On the other hand, you *can* design your own datastructure that would ensure what you want. A typechecker then could assert that at least one value exists if you define your own datastructure, e.g.

```
type MinOneList<T> = {
  value: T,
  next: MinOneList<T> | null,
};
```

so if you have

```
var foo: MinOneList<T> = ...
```

you are guaranteed that `foo.value` exists, so the list has at least one item. For it to qualify as empty, the type would have to be `MinOneList<T> | null`.